# How can I maintain the scroll position after window resize?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, google-chrome-extension, scrolltop

I am building a chrome extension that will let you save your scroll location on a webpage. The issue I'm running into is often when you resize the page the content you are looking for may have been pushed around and is no longer at the same scroll location. I've been trying to build something that would adjust the scroll location to fit the adjusted size. I found [this solution](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesKyle/RmNap/), and it's closer to what I am looking for, but it's also still some what inaccurate. It uses the document's height and the scroll location to figure out where you are percentage wise. Then it tries to maintain that percent as you resize the page. Unfortunately that percent is not entirely accurate.

I have integrated it into my extension, and I have been trying it out on this [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antonio_Sant%27Elia)(I liked the drawings). I've added screenshots below to show how off it can be. I have tried to multiply the height delta by a constant, but there is no single number that works. I have tried to round the numbers to different points, but same problem. What can I do to make the scroll location more accurate?

**Manifest.json**

```
{
    "name": "ScrollMark",
    "description": "Save your place on a page",
    "version": "1.1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "content_scripts": [{
        "js": ["jquery.min.js", "contentScript.js"],
        "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"]
  }]
}
```

**contentScript.js**

```
$(document).keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        console.group("User hit enter");
        console.log('window size', $(window).width(), $(window).height());
        console.log('document size', $(document).width(), $(document).outerHeight(true));           
        console.log('scroll top', $(document).scrollTop());
        console.groupEnd();
    }
});
(function () {
    var pageHeight = $(document).outerHeight(true), //get hight of element, including margin
        scrollPosition = $(document).scrollTop(),
        scrollPercent = scrollPosition / pageHeight,
        resizing = false,
        resizeTimer;
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if (!resizing) {
            scrollPosition = $(document).scrollTop();
            scrollPercent = scrollPosition / pageHeight;
        }
    });
    $(window).resize(function () {
        resizing = true;
        clearTimeout(resizeTimer);
        resizeTimer = setTimeout(function () {
            resizing = false
        }, 500);
        pageHeight = $(document).outerHeight(true);
        $(document).scrollTop(scrollPercent * pageHeight);
    });
})();
```

[image: 100% View]
100% View
Expected scroll location: 962
Actual scroll Location: 962
[image: 75% View]
75% View
Expected scroll location: 1207
Actual scroll Location: 1211
[image: 50% View]
50% View
Expected scroll location: 1534
Actual scroll Location: 1577
[image: 25% View]
25% View
Expected scroll location: 2852
Actual scroll Location: 2708

Answer (score 2):

To have it exactly the way you want it is unfortunately impossible as you can't know how a responsive design will handle the content after a resize (well, you could, but it would require years to write such a code).

But, if I may give you a piece of advice, it would be to rely on the topmost visible element. You could go through all the DOM tree and find the static element which is the nearest to the top of the visible part of the screen (using offset properties etc.) and then store its full and precise CSS selector.

Then, all you would need to do to restore the scroll position is:

```
var el = document.querySelector(storedSelector);

el && el.scrollIntoView();
```

This won't be as precise as you may want but it should be OK.

If you still want more precision, you can store in addition to the selector, some offset values, and scroll a bit more, but this may be really tricky.

Hope this will help.

Comment: I took this approach in a project I worked on, where I got the first :visible object and used scrollTo to try to main the scrollbar's position after the browser was resized.  It worked most of the time when the user was increasing the size of the browser, but when shrinking, things got dicey. I had to add code to detect if the window was shrinking and get the LAST item instead of the first (if window is growing, this worked fine). I banged my head on desk a lot with this project - hope this helps someone hehe

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the same matter but didn't find anything promising. I'm a beginner in js but made a working script. It's choosing html element visible on the screen during scrolling and maintain the scroll position in relation with this chosen element during resizing. I'm quiet convinced that my code is not perfect but this is what I could do without a lot of experience. hope I could help to anybody.

```js
var html_tags = [];
 var public_closest;
 var from_top_pos;
 var public_body_height;

 
function start() {
  when_scroll();
  when_resize();
 }


function when_resize() {
 
  var count_elements = document.body.childNodes;
  var element = count_elements[public_closest];
  var closest_pos = count_elements[public_closest].offsetTop;
  var window_height = window.pageYOffset;
  
  window.scrollTo(0, closest_pos + from_top_pos);
 }




function when_scroll() {

 var window_height = document.body.scrollHeight;
 
 if (isNaN(public_body_height)) {
   public_body_height = window_height;
  }
 
 
 if (public_body_height != window_height) {
  public_body_height = window_height;
 } else {

  var how_many_elems = document.body.childNodes;
  var closest_number;
  var i;
  
  for (i = 0; i < how_many_elems.length; i++) {
    html_tags[i] = how_many_elems[i].offsetTop;
   }
    
  var closest;
  
  for (i = 0; i < html_tags.length; i++) { 
   if (isNaN(html_tags[i])) {
    } else {
     
     if (isNaN(closest)) {
       closest = html_tags[i];
      }
       
     if (Math.abs(window.pageYOffset - html_tags[i]) <= Math.abs(window.pageYOffset - closest)) {
        closest = html_tags[i];
        closest_number = i;
       } 
    }
   }
   
   if (isNaN(public_closest)) {
    } else {
     how_many_elems[public_closest].style.border = "dotted 2px #33aaff";
    }
   
  public_closest = closest_number;
  how_many_elems[closest_number].style.border = "dotted 4px #FF55AA";
    
  var count_elements = document.body.childNodes;
  var element = count_elements[public_closest];
  var current_height = count_elements[public_closest].offsetTop;
  var window_height = window.pageYOffset;
  var height_difference = window_height - current_height;
  
  from_top_pos = height_difference;

 }
}
```

```css
body>div {
  float:left;
  width:35%;
  min-width:200px;
  min-height:200px;
  max-height:1000px;
  margin:30px 10px;
  padding:20px 10px;
  font-size:22px;
  color:#33aaff;
  background-color:#ffffff;
  border:dotted 2px #33aaff;
  overflow:hidden;
 }
```

```html
<body onload="start()" onscroll="when_scroll()" onresize="when_resize()">

<div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque sed urna pellentesque, commodo ante ut, porttitor est. Nullam viverra dignissim sem, ac auctor dui. Phasellus ut neque odio. Nullam vel massa ut nisl sollicitudin ullamcorper a at     urna. Mauris nec venenatis sapien, et auctor ex. Donec vel urna vulputate, volutpat augue non, bibendum quam. Maecenas congue id justo nec feugiat. Mauris non molestie leo. Duis non tincidunt nibh. Duis tristique dapibus sapien id commodo. In et tempor lorem.</p>
</div>

<div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque sed urna pellentesque, commodo ante ut, porttitor est. Nullam viverra dignissim sem, ac auctor dui. Phasellus ut neque odio. Nullam vel massa ut nisl sollicitudin ullamcorper a at urna. Mauris nec venenatis sapien, et auctor ex. Donec vel urna vulputate, volutpat augue non, bibendum quam. Maecenas congue id justo nec feugiat. Mauris non molestie leo.</p>
</div>

<div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque sed urna pellentesque, commodo ante ut, porttitor est. Nullam viverra dignissim sem, ac auctor dui. Phasellus ut neque odio. Nullam vel massa ut nisl sollicitudin ullamcorper a at urna. Mauris nec venenatis sapien, et auctor ex. Donec vel urna vulputate, volutpat augue non, bibendum quam.</p>
</div>

<div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque sed urna pellentesque, commodo ante ut, porttitor est. ullam viverra dignissim sem, ac auctor dui. Phasellus ut neque odio. Nullam vel massa ut nisl sollicitudin ullamcorper a at urna. Mauris nec venenatis sapien, et auctor ex.</p>
</div>

<div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque sed urna pellentesque, commodo ante ut, porttitor est. Nullam viverra dignissim sem, ac auctor dui. Phasellus ut neque odio. Nullam vel massa ut nisl sollicitudin ullamcorper a at urna.</p>
</div>

<div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque sed urna pellentesque, commodo ante ut, porttitor est. Nullam viverra dignissim sem, ac auctor dui. Phasellus ut neque odio.</p>
</div>

<div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque sed urna pellentesque, commodo ante ut, porttitor est.Nullam viverra dignissim sem, ac auctor dui. Phasellus ut neque odio. Nullam vel massa ut nisl sollicitudin ullamcorper a at urna. Mauris nec venenatis sapien, et auctor ex. Donec vel urna vulputate, volutpat augue non, bibendum quam. Maecenas congue id justo nec feugiat. Mauris non molestie leo. Duis non tincidunt nibh. Duis tristique dapibus sapien id commodo. In et tempor lorem.</p>
</div>

<div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque sed urna pellentesque, commodo ante ut, porttitor est. Nullam viverra dignissim sem, ac auctor dui. Phasellus ut neque odio. Nullam vel massa ut nisl sollicitudin ullamcorper a at urna. Mauris nec venenatis sapien, et auctor ex. Donec vel urna vulputate, volutpat augue non, bibendum quam. Maecenas congue id justo nec feugiat. Mauris non molestie leo.</p>
</div>

<div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque sed urna pellentesque, commodo ante ut, porttitor est. Nullam viverra dignissim sem, ac auctor dui. Phasellus ut neque odio. Nullam vel massa ut nisl sollicitudin ullamcorper a at urna. Mauris nec venenatis sapien, et auctor ex. Donec vel urna vulputate, volutpat augue non, bibendum quam.</p>
</div>

<div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque sed urna pellentesque, commodo ante ut, porttitor est. Nullam viverra dignissim sem, ac auctor dui. Phasellus ut neque odio. Nullam vel massa ut nisl sollicitudin ullamcorper a at urna. Mauris nec venenatis sapien, et auctor ex.</p>
</div>

<div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque sed urna pellentesque, commodo ante ut, porttitor est. Nullam viverra dignissim sem, ac auctor dui. Phasellus ut neque odio. Nullam vel massa ut nisl sollicitudin ullamcorper a at urna.</p>
</div>

<div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque sed urna pellentesque, commodo ante ut, porttitor est. Nullam viverra dignissim sem, ac auctor dui. Phasellus ut neque odio.</p>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: I don't know a better approach than this, but I will mention that running so much code on each scroll event is likely to reduce the user's frame rate. It might make sense to use a timer to limit the rate at which you detect the element closest to the top of the screen.